# Who taps my opponent's creatures if I control my opponent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Solitary Sanctuary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Solitary%20Sanctuary) is a new card from *Wilds of Eldraine* that reads, in part:

> Whenever you tap an untapped creature an opponent controls, put a +1/+1 counter on target creature you control.

(The set has several other cards with similar trigger conditions.) Suppose I'm controlling my opponent's turn with [Mindslaver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mindslaver). If I activate an ability of a creature they control that has {T} in its cost, does Solitary Sanctuary trigger? If I attack with one of their creatures, does it trigger?

Comment: You might be interested: [Does Emrakul, the Promised End trigger if the player casting it is being controlled?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/54494/does-emrakul-the-promised-end-trigger-if-the-player-casting-it-is-being-control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not trigger, your opponent is still tapping their own creatures, not you. As far as the game is concerned, you are telling your opponent what to do and they are still the one doing it. If the game considered you were the one tapping their permanents, tapping their lands would give you mana not them for example. This effect triggers from effects like [Freeze in Place](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Freeze%20in%20Place) or [Three Bowls of Porridge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Three%20Bowls%20of%20Porridge)